# Question about QR decomposition

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to know whether two matrices have the same Q in the QR-decomposition without explicitly calculating the QR decomposition.

ie:
$$A = Q_1R_1$$ and $$B = Q_2R_2$$

Is it possible to recognize that $$Q_1=Q_2$$ or $$Q_1 \ne Q_2$$ just by looking at A and B or their properties? (ie: is there some shortcut method to recognize this, without actually calculating the Q matrices).

Comment: In principle, yes: $Q_1=Q_2$ (up to signs of the columns) if and only if $\operatorname{span}\{a_1,\dots,a_i\}=\operatorname{span}\{b_1,\dots,b_i\}$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$, where $a_i,b_i$ are the columns of $A,B$ respectively. However this may be just as hard to check as computing the QR decompositions.